# Is there any extra benefit from making payments before Nova requests one?

Tags: tales-of-xillia-2

The game will interrupt you to make debt payments at various intervals. But it will not bug you until you are holding the original interval in your wallet.

For example, if the full payment is 10,000 gald and you pay 1,000, the new amount due is 9,000. In this case, the game would not ask for payment until a full 10,000 debt was reached again.

If I make a full payment before I actually reach the next interval is there any tangible benefit or reward (i.e. If the interval is 10,000 but I pay a full 10,000 before ever having over 10,000 gald in my wallet at one time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reward for making payments when you're supposed to because of quest-related things (ie. Opening up a new area).  But most of the other full payments you make towards your debt will actually send you a gift at Ludger's house.  Some of these are common things, like Kitty Krisps, but you can also get Skill books, which will teach Ludger and company new skills.  For example, one of the skill books I got teaches Ludger Leia's Lottery skill, which has a chance of doubling the amount of Gald you get.

I'm not sure if the rewards are in a set order, so I'm afraid you may get different things than I do.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if this answers my question. I am going to do a few tests when I do my second run through. (Also the Lottery Skill comes from Leia herself not from the debt).

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're asking.  Making partial payments (that don't hit the payment limit) has no bonus.  It's every full payment that gives you a bonus.  ie. If your current payment amount is 10,000, every time you pay 10,000, you've made a full payment, and if it was an extra, optional payment, you'll probably get a bonus package in Ludger's house.

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was a reward for paying the 10,000 early (Actively opening the menu and paying 10,000 over time) versus having the menu forcefully opened because you are currently holding 10,000 gald.

Comment: It's all story-based.  If your current goal isn't to make a payment on your debt, then it's considered an extra payment, regardless of whether or not you opened the window yourself.

Comment: Having gotten to the last chapter and paid off the loan (not as bad as expected since Elite EX monsters give out like 300-800k rewards) it couldn't possibly matter since there are no more 'minumum payments' to get early. The whole lump sum left is your 'next payment' for the latter half of the game.